# Adobe Illustrator CS6 - Making a pattern: H and V Spacing not available

Tags: adobe-illustrator

So I'm trying to make a pattern in Illustrator and I want more space in between the tiles; I see the H Spacing and V Spacing options, but they're grayed out. How do I use them?

Answer (score 0):

Click the "Size Tile to Art" and the H and V spacing options will become available.